# Inverse image of surjective, continuous function between metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis

In a proof I am doing, I am given a metric space $X$ and a surjective, continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$

In my proof, I want to use that $f^{-1}(Y) = X$.

My argument for this is that by definition, $f^{-1}(Y) = \{x \in X | f(x) \in Y\}$. And because $f$ is defined for all $x \in X$, this must be $X$.

Wouldn't this be correct even if $f$ wasn't surjective? For instance, if $f: X \rightarrow A$, where $A\subset Y$, wouldn't $f^{-1}(Y)$ still be $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.  If $f:S\to T$ is any function at all between two sets $S$ and $T$, then $f^{-1}(T)=S$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $f^{-1}(Y) = X$ is always true. What the surjectivity tells you is that $f(X) = Y.$